# React components not re-rendering after state changes

Tags: javascript, oauth, reactjs

I am learning react and followed this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-react-flux-app-with-user-authentication to add authentication to my app.

Sadly after completing it I realised it only updates the login button and you have to refresh the browser to see the authenticated content.

I've searched all over and tried setting state and props and passing them from parent to children but all to no avail.

Below are my three components, any help massively appreciated, I've looked all over the web & studied other React Apps already.

Thanks.

App.js

```
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PlayButton from './PlayButton';
import SlotMachine from './SlotMachine';

import AuthActions from '../actions/AuthActions';
import AuthStore from '../stores/AuthStore';



class AppComponent extends Component {



    componentWillMount() {
        this.lock = new Auth0Lock('3RhBq3qZaZARDQae7PtbH59wyP9xe7Ld', 'wolftiger.eu.auth0.com');
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authenticated: AuthStore.isAuthenticated()
        }
    }


    login() {
        // We can call the show method from Auth0Lock,
        // which is passed down as a prop, to allow
        // the user to log in
        //console.log("parent login", this.props);
        this.props.lock.show((err,profile,token) => {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
                //console.log(err);
                return;

            }
            AuthActions.logUserIn(profile, token);
            //this.props.login();
            this.setState({authenticated:true});
        });
    }

    logout() {
        AuthActions.logUserOut();
        //this.props.logout();
        this.setState({authenticated:false});
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this, this.props, this.props.children, this.state);
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="medium-12 small-12">
                        <h1>Spin and Win</h1>

                        { !this.state.authenticated ? (
                        <div className="medium-12 small-12">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/960x360"/>
                        </div>
                        ) : (
                            <SlotMachine state={this.state} props={this.props} >
                            </SlotMachine>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="medium-12 small-12">
                        <PlayButton
                            lock={this.lock}
                            state={this.state}
                            login={this.login}
                            logout={this.logout}
                        >
                        </PlayButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
  }
}

//AppComponent.defaultProps = {};


export default AppComponent;
```

SlotMachine.js

```
'use strict';

import React            from 'react';
import Slots            from './Slots';
import SpinButton       from './SpinButton';
import StatusMessage    from './StatusMessage';
import Chances    from './Chances';

const propTypes = {
  currentUser: React.PropTypes.object
};


// The SlotMachine React class handles the entirety of this very small app.
class SlotMachine extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slotPositions: this.getRandomState(),
      chancesLeft: 3//this value must be stored in the db

    };
    //console.log(this.state.slotPositions);
  }

  // Generates random initial state for slots.
  componentWillMount() {

  }



  //getInitialState() {
  //  return {slotPositions: this.getRandomState()};
  //}

  genSlotValue(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }

  // Generates random landing values for slots using genSlotValue defined at the end of the file
  getRandomState() {
    //console.log(genSlotValue(), genSlotValue(), genSlotValue());
    return [
      genSlotValue(),
      genSlotValue(),
      genSlotValue()
    ];
  }

  useChance() {
      var noOfChances = this.state.chancesLeft;
      this.setState({chancesLeft: minusOne(noOfChances)})
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    //console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
    //ReactDOM.render(newProps);
  }

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    //console.log(event, this, this.state);
    this.useChance();
    console.log(event, this, this.state, this.props);
    event.preventDefault();
    // Set count to 0 before each button press
    let count = 0;
    // Set a random state as the final state of all slots before we start spinning
    let finalState = this.getRandomState();
    // Make sure we start with a fresh state for all slots on each spin
    let currentState = this.getRandomState();
    //console.log(currentState,finalState)
    // Spinning happens here
    var makeSpin = function(){
      let nextState = currentState;
      let hasChanged = false;
      var spinButton = document.getElementById('spin-button');

      // Evaluate whether or not slots are on their final destination, spin to nextState if not
      for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (count < 9 || currentState[i] != finalState[i]) {

          nextState[i] = (currentState[i]+1)%3;
          hasChanged = true;
          spinButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
          //spinButton.setTextContent('Spinning!');
          spinButton.classList.add('spinning');
        }
        //Re-enable spin button
        if (count >= 9){
          //console.log('count more than 9')
          spinButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
          //  spinButton.setTextContent('Spin!');
          spinButton.classList.remove('spinning');
        }
      }

      // Moves reel to the next assigned state if it's not yet on it's final value.
      this.setState({slotPositions: nextState, isFinal: !hasChanged})

      // Stops reel spinning if we've hit the final state's value
      if(!hasChanged) {
        return;
      }
      currentState = this.state.slotPositions;
      setTimeout(makeSpin, 100);
      count++;
      //console.log(count);
    }.bind(this);


    // Actually spin
    makeSpin();
  }




  render() {

      // Define winning states
      let sp = this.state.slotPositions;
      let isWinning = (sp[0] == sp[1]) && (sp[1] == sp[2]);

      // Make sure winner, winnerClass, and winnerImage strings are undefined until there's an actual win
      let winner = '';
      let winnerClass = '';
      let winnerImage = '';

      // Make sure we're only displaying the win state on final slot positions
      if(isWinning && this.state.isFinal){
        winner = [
          <h2>You've won John Lewis vouchers!</h2>,
          <h2>You've won M&amp;S vouchers!</h2>,
          <h2>You've won Size vouchers!!</h2>
        ][sp[0]];
        winnerClass = [
          'coffee',
          'tea',
          'espresso'
        ][sp[0]];
        winnerImage = [
          <div id='coffee-img' className='tossing win-img'></div>,
          <div id='tea-img' className='tossing win-img'></div>,
          <div id='espresso-img' className='tossing win-img'></div>
        ][sp[0]];
    }

    //console.log(this, this.props, this.props.state.authenticated);
    return (
      <main className='react-slots'>
        <div className="medium-12 small-12">
          <Chances chancesLeft={this.state.chancesLeft}  />
          <section className="machine">
            <Slots slotPositions={this.state.slotPositions} />
            <div className="spin row">
              <SpinButton onButtonClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)} />
            </div>
          </section>
          <section className="win row">
            <StatusMessage winner={winner} winnerClass={winnerClass} winnerImage={winnerImage} />
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }

}

// Generates a random slot value.
function genSlotValue(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function minusOne(value){
  return value - 1;
}



SlotMachine.propTypes = propTypes;


export default SlotMachine;
```

PlayButton.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AuthStore from '../stores/AuthStore';

// Creates Spin Button
class PlayButton extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            authenticated: AuthStore.isAuthenticated()
        }
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this, this.props, this.state.authenticated);
        return (
            <div>
            {!this.state.authenticated ? (
                <div className="medium-4 small-12">
                    <button id="play-button" className="play-button" onClick={this.props.login.bind(this)}>Play!</button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div className="medium-4 small-12">
                    <button id="play-button" className="play-button" onClick={this.props.logout.bind(this)}>Log out!</button>
                </div>
            )}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default PlayButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not importing `AuthStore` and `AuthActions`. Also where is the `lock` being passed as a props into `AppComponent`. You have to make sure lock is available in the props before you can do `this.props.lock`. It would be easier to figure out what is going on if you can restructure your code into different files. From the tutorial, `this.lock` was passed as a props into the `Header` Component, and then `this.props.lock.show` was then called in the Header Component, in your own case you should probably just do `this.lock.show`inside your `login` method instead of `this.props.lock.show`

Comment: thanks for getting back. My code is in different files but i pasted it all in here so you could see what is happening. The Authentication is working but i need to set state on all components and get them render, currently only the login button itself gets re-rendered in it's authenticated state. The rest only shows authenticated on referesh. I can show you the project if you it helps

Comment: I've divided the code above to show you the different files and imports

Comment: Okay, thanks for dividing the code. Which components do you want re-rendered in the authenticated state, What's the difference between when they were authenticated and when they were unauthenticated. From the code, I can see that only the button changes

Comment: if you look at App.js there is a placeholder image or the SlotMachine component that need to rerender and display the appropriate content

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `SlotMachine` like `<SlotMachine state={this.state} props={this.props} />` instead of like `<SlotMachine state={this.state} props={this.props} ></SlotMachine>` because the latter assumes it's gonna have children components/elements inside it. Also you should probably rename the props you are passing into it. It's definitely gonna be confusing to write `this.props.props`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make any difference, the component isn't being re-rendered, i maybe have to maybe use componentWillReceive props and setState? setState is supposed to trigger a re-render of a component

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by configuring react-router and loading the new component that way, this forced the newly loaded component to check for the authentication and display the appropriate content.

My app doesn't actually need routing as it's embedded in a page, I'd still like to find a solution without routing but for now it's enough.